# How do I convert a string to a Python Decimal in German locale (with comma instead of a point)

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string to a python decimal.

This works

```
from decimal import *
mystr = '123.45'
print(Decimal(mystr))
```

But when I want to use the thousand separator and the locale, it doesn't.
Converting to float works fine.

```
from locale import *
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,'German_Germany.1252')
from decimal import *
mystr = '1.234,56'
print(atof(mystr))
print(Decimal(mystr))
```

returns the float and an error

```
1234.56
InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

Is there a right way to convert the string without manually transforming it via float or hackier solutions? FYA, my current hacky solution is:

```
 print(Decimal(f'{atof(mystr):2.2f}'))
```

Comment: what's wrong with `Decimal(atof(mystr))` ? (note the output of your test doesn't match: here I get `1234.56`)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've used that and get nasty rounding errors when adding the decimals I generated that way. It also feels like a hack to me...

Comment: yes, there are some rounding errors but it's because of floating point representation, it's not really rounding. It's just that `Decimal` doesn't handle locale. Doesn't seem like a hack to me.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit suprised that Decimal can't handle locale. If it doesn't, then a hack is necessary...

Comment: maybe sumbit a python PEP (not that easy). That would be an interesting feature. @MartijnPieters any thoughts on that, would that be a good idea? (sorry for bothering you)

Comment: I had a similar thought during lunch break... (basically debugging the standard library to see what's going on and if it's patchable from my intermediate python skills) - then researching how to do a PEP or draw attention to it...

Comment: I didn't take any lunch break, well, I took it on SO with my friend the apple :) Such a good idea could be accepted. The difficulty seems to be: how to write a PEP properly. Of course that would help if you had some implementation ideas.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I did some research and here is the solution:

```
import decimal
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
mystr = '1.234,56'
num = locale.atof(mystr, decimal.Decimal)

print('{}'.format(num))
print('{:n}'.format(num))
```

---

```
1234.56
1.234,56
```

Under the hood [`locale.atof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.atof) calls [`delocalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.delocalize) function which does exactly what @lsma suggests.

Comment: This looks promising (and non-hacky). I`ll check it and mark this solved, if it works for me.

Comment: Works (almost) and good enough to accept as answer. I had to use `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC,'German_Germany.1252')` on my German Windows machine using Python 3.6, your setting caused "locale.Error: unsupported locale setting".

Comment: @576i, i tested on ubuntu. The locale names might be OS-specific and should be installed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, basically we format the string according the locale before converting:

```
from locale import *
from decimal import *

def format_decimal(s):
   return '{0:n}'.format(s)

setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,'German_Germany.1252')
thousandSep = localeconv()['thousands_sep']
decimalPoint = localeconv()['decimal_point']
mystr = '1.234,56'.replace(thousandSep, '').replace(decimalPoint, '.')
print(atof(mystr))
print(format_decimal(Decimal(mystr)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The locale options didn't work for me, perhaps because I have very little on this machine in the way of internationalization, so I offer a solution that relies only on string manipulation:

```
numbr = 1234.56

mystr = '{:,.2f}'.format(numbr) # Ugly American format
mystr_orig = mystr # Ugly (but saved for later!) American format

mystr = mystr.replace(',', '{0}')
mystr = mystr.replace('.', '{1}')

print(mystr_orig)
print(mystr.format('.', ','))
```